# What is a directive in Apache configuration?

Tags: apache, configuration, apache2, httpd.conf

Why all the configurations in Apache HTTP server are called directives? What is the meaning of directive? Curios to know the reason.

Answer (score 11):

Apache directives are a set of rules which define how your server should run, number of clients that can access your server, etc. you can change them by editing the httpd.conf and related files to meet your requirements